# Dropping Json object on html page in asp.net mvc2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-2

i m using asp.net mvc2 and i want to drop some json objects from my controller similar to validation metadata. when we call Html.ClientValidation() before our form it drops some javascript on the page like

```
<javascript type="text/javascript">
    <!--CDATA[validation metadata]-->
</javascript>
```

i want to have some json objects dropped in my page that i can use through jquery

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { foo = "bar" }) %>;
</script>
```

Now you can use the `obj` global variable:

```
alert(obj.foo);
```